# Chrome Handling dataTransfer.types as Object

Tags: javascript, data-transfer

I'm having a really funky issue with dataTransfer in Chrome 24.0.1312.5 that I'm hoping I could get some ideas on.  Basically, I have a `nodeIterator` that singles out some useful elements from an iframe.  For each of these elements, I'm adding event listeners to permit dropping of content.  I'm having a problem with this bit of code:

```
currentNode.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
    // Only accept images
    // Error occurs in below conditional
    if (e.dataTransfer.types.contains('text/uri-list')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here's the portion of my code that adds the data:

```
figure.draggable = 'true';
figure.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/uri-list', img.src);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', img.alt);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('application/x-trash.delete', img.id);
});
```

The error I get in the console is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object text/plain,text/uri-list,application/x-trash.delete
has no method 'contains'
```

I've written a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3LMT/13/) that should be able to reproduce this issue, but of course it works just fine.

Any ideas of something I might be missing?  Or other relevant portions of code I should check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that dataTransfer.types returned in Chrome is a Array.You can use indexOf() instead of contains method to workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I ended up implementing this functionality in an entirely different way so I can't check whether it would have resolved my issue, but it does appear as such.  If there are no other responses in the next week or so, I'll accept your answer.